# What is command "confighandler"?

Tags: 20.04, top

When I run `top` on my Ubuntu, I see a weird process which is always taking up 8-10% CPU. The COMMAND column says `confighandler`. It runs under `root`.

When I run `which confighandler`, it desn't return anything.

Is this a legit system process, or is there something fishy going on?

Comment: Please include a screenshot - thanx.

Comment: I found that the FortiClient for Linux uses a component called *confighandler webserver* ([see here](https://www.fortiguard.com/psirt/FG-IR-21-226)). Does it ring any bells?

Comment: yes, it's probably FortiClient. Thanks @ArturMeinild

Comment: @ArturMeinild make it an answer ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the FortiClient for Linux uses a component called *confighandler webserver* ([see here](https://www.fortiguard.com/psirt/FG-IR-21-226)).

So it's most likely the FortiClient for Linux running.